# Defining variables using foreach

Tags: c#, variables, foreach, syntax

```
int[] xarray = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };
foreach (int x in xarray)
{
    double x[] = xPT / 20 * [];
    double z[] = Math.Pow(x[] / Hd , 1.85) / 2 * Hd);
}

        /* My previous code was;
        x0 = xPT / 20 * 0;
        x1 = xPT / 20 * 1;
        x2 = xPT / 20 * 2;
        x3 = xPT / 20 * 3;
        x4 = xPT / 20 * 4;
        x5 = xPT / 20 * 5;
        x6 = xPT / 20 * 6;
        x7 = xPT / 20 * 7;
        x8 = xPT / 20 * 8;
        x9 = xPT / 20 * 9;
        x10 = xPT / 20 * 10;
        x11 = xPT / 20 * 11;
        x12 = xPT / 20 * 12;
        x13 = xPT / 20 * 13;
        x14 = xPT / 20 * 14;
        x15 = xPT / 20 * 15;
        x16 = xPT / 20 * 16;
        x17 = xPT / 20 * 17;
        x18 = xPT / 20 * 18;
        x19 = xPT / 20 * 19;
        x20 = xPT / 20 * 20;
        z0 = Math.Pow(x0 / Hd, 1.85) / 2 * Hd;
        z1 = Math.Pow(x1 / Hd, 1.85) / 2 * Hd;
        z2 = Math.Pow(x2 / Hd, 1.85) / 2 * Hd;
        z3 = Math.Pow(x3 / Hd, 1.85) / 2 * Hd;
        z4 = Math.Pow(x4 / Hd, 1.85) / 2 * Hd;
        z5 = Math.Pow(x5 / Hd, 1.85) / 2 * Hd;
        z6 = Math.Pow(x6 / Hd, 1.85) / 2 * Hd;
        z7 = Math.Pow(x7 / Hd, 1.85) / 2 * Hd;
        z8 = Math.Pow(x8 / Hd, 1.85) / 2 * Hd;
        z9 = Math.Pow(x9 / Hd, 1.85) / 2 * Hd;
        z10 = Math.Pow(x10 / Hd, 1.85) / 2 * Hd;
        z11 = Math.Pow(x11 / Hd, 1.85) / 2 * Hd;
        z12 = Math.Pow(x12 / Hd, 1.85) / 2 * Hd;
        z13 = Math.Pow(x13 / Hd, 1.85) / 2 * Hd;
        z14 = Math.Pow(x14 / Hd, 1.85) / 2 * Hd;
        z15 = Math.Pow(x15 / Hd, 1.85) / 2 * Hd;
        z16 = Math.Pow(x16 / Hd, 1.85) / 2 * Hd;
        z17 = Math.Pow(x17 / Hd, 1.85) / 2 * Hd;
        z18 = Math.Pow(x18 / Hd, 1.85) / 2 * Hd;
        z19 = Math.Pow(x19 / Hd, 1.85) / 2 * Hd;
        z20 = Math.Pow(x20 / Hd, 1.85) / 2 * Hd;
         */
```

as you can see above, my previous code was too long. (only 2 item is listed above but i have more in my code.) I want to define variables in a single line.
I feel ashamed to ask these simple questions on stack overflow but I can't find the correct syntax for this on web.

Comment: @rory.ap Really, to me it seems that above code does not even complie

Comment: You need to define your `x` and `z` arrays before the foreach, then populate them in the foreach accordingly.

Comment: You've double declared x. once for the loop var and again as an array inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `for` loop to initialize `xarray` also:

```
var size = 21;

var xarray = new int[size];
var x = new double[size];
var z = new double[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    xarray[i] = i;
    x[i] = xPT / 20 * xarray[i];
    z[i] = Math.Pow(x[i] / Hd, 1.85) / 2 * Hd;
}
```

Comment: Hello,
MessageBox.Show(x[i].ToString()); when i write this to end of your code, it shows every value as expected. but, what if I want to obtain a specific value like x[7]?

Comment: figured this part out myself. MessageBox.Show(x[5].ToString()); this answer is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 3):

This can actually be done rather easily using Linq.  `Enumerable.Range` can give you the 0-21 values you want then just use `Select` to run your formula on each one for the `x` values, then do another `Select` on `x` using the second formula to get the `z` values.

```
var x = Enumerable.Range(0,21).Select(i => xPT / 20.0 * i).ToList();
var z = x.Select(xi => Math.Pow(xi / Hd, 1.85) / 2.0 * Hd).ToList();
```

Or you can use `ToArray` if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the two arrays before the loop.  I would suggest to use a normal for-loop. This will give you an indexing variable at hand that you can use to point to the positions in the array. Also it will allow you to set the length of the arrays and avoid the array `xarray` because the indexing variable will run through all those values if you start at `i=0` increment it with the step size of 1 `i++` and stop at `i<=20`

```
int finalNumber = 20;
double x[] = new double[finalNumber+1]  // +1 because you want to include the value 20
double z[] = new double[finalNumber+1]

for (int i = 0; i <= finalNumber; i++)
{
    x[i] = xPT / 20 * i;
    z[i] = Math.Pow(x[i] / Hd , 1.85) / 2 * Hd);
}
```

Here is a [small introduction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) in for-loops and the use of the indexing variable

Comment: I don't know why but its not working. I face some errors when i paste this code.
"   Cannot implicitly convert type 'double[]' to 'double'   "
"   Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'double'    "

Comment: @Meriç I made a mistake. I corrected it in the calculation I used only the index instead of `x[i]`. Now it should work as expected